# Maven does not stop on error using selenium webdriver 2

Tags: java, maven, selenium, jenkins, webdriver

I am sorry if this is already answered, I tried to find a solution and still not getting anything.

I am working in `Eclipse` and `Selenium webdriver` and running the code via `MAVEN`.

My problem is that `Maven` continues running forever if an error was found, `Selenium driver` is not closed until I close the browser's window.

I can do it manually if anything happens in local, but the problem is when I try to use `Jenknins`, If anything fails, `Jenkins` job is running until I stop it.

Can you please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Couple of questions here. How many test cases are there? Do you close the browser once a test case completes? The best way is to close the browser as soon as test case completes. This ensures no matter what other test cases continue. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, I am making a full application that takes information about csslocators and xpath from a database and then interactuate with them. IE I made a batch of 3 tests running in a loop inside JAVA, only changing data adquired from database. I have added @after method but maven still does not close browser after find an error. I can not find the problem...

Comment: @Daniel, put alwaysRun=true in the `@AfterMethod`

Comment: Thanks, Can you say me what to import for that? I am getting cannot find symbol in JAVA.

Comment: Ok, I find the imports by testng but now, I have no tests launched... Weird thing I put alwaysrun in beforemethod and aftermethod...

Comment: I have to left testng because my code is made for junit, can I add alwaysrun using Junit?

Comment: @Daniel First of all its not maven but junit/testng which has @ after annotation. Can you share the stack trace. Also do you loop through the same @ test annotation or do you have multiple @ test annotations?

Comment: I am not using @test for nothing, I am calling methods from Setup to perform the different tests. I.E.:

TEST1 { ...... }

TEST2 { ...... }

!!Before 
SETUP { if test1 is in the batch call it from here }

!!TEST empty void

!!After teardown telling to quit webdriver

Comment: Hi guys, Thanks everyone for your help, finally I find the solution, the thing is that I have a main class to be able to compile a jar file, so the thing was to place the after method in the main class not in the tests class... If anyone of you have the same problem, remember to call driver.quit from the class previosly called in main I.E. tests.driver.quit(). Hope this help anyone more.. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

**The important thing is to call `WebDriver.quit()` as you finish testing.**

Usually in JUnit, this usually means calling it in one of these places:

- a method or class annotated with `@After` or `@AfterClass`,
- a property or class annotated with `@Rule` or `@ClassRule`,
- a RunListener class, via the `testFinished()` or `testRunFinished()` methods,
- a suitable runner class or
- static teardown code.

You should choose the opposite to wherever you create your driver object. If all your tests are Selenium WebDriver ones and if you intend to run them sequentially in a single browser window (I think that this is the most common situation for smallish projects), then a single RunListener can hide this code nicely.  As an example:

```
public class WebDriverContext extends RunListener {
  public static WebDriver DRIVER; // Pretending to be final
  public void testRunStarted(Description descr) {
    DRIVER = new FirefoxDriver();
  }
  public void testRunFinished(Result result) {
    DRIVER.quit();
  }
}
```

(Credit to the OP for this answer, in his comment above. He's apparently gone from SO now, so he's not going to be able to post his answer here. I've also expanded it a fair bit.)